# iOS switch network configuration

Tags: ios, network, proxy, configuration-profiles

On our iPhones (a lot of test devices) we switch often between a plain network connection and a connection with a proxy.
The normal flow require

1. Go to `setting`
2. Select `wifi preference`
3. `enable proxy`
4. type the proxy address

Is there any way to "save" the proxy setting and enable/disable with a single button?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into configuration profiles.

Their contents are described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

You can build two profiles, one with and the other without proxy, and you would be able to create a link to each. Add those two links to a single webpage, and then add that page to Home Screen.

That's two taps rather than one, though.

Another option is two make two separate pages, each with a javascript redirect to download the profile. You could then save each of the pages to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of jcaron's answer, you can combine profiles with Shortcuts to have a somewhat streamlined solution.

I wrote [a blog post](https://jmbeach.github.io/blog/ios/iphone/proxy/2021/02/20/ios-proxy-switcher.html) describing this in much more detail, but essentially, here are the steps:

1. Make your phone supervised
2. Create a shortcut to open the url to a profile that sets your proxy settings. Example [here](https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/8a186134ccca23818e5b40d4f4f90247#file-charlesproxy-mobileconfig)
3. Use the shortcut to download your profile quickly

You can combine this with another shortcut for just navigating to the profile settings page to easily delete the profile when you're done with the proxy.